# firefox console fails to define a varaible

Tags: javascript, firefox, console, xmlhttprequest, fetch

after I excute that code in the firefox console, I receive an  erorr thay says" ReferenceError: abc is not defined". how do I fix that to make it work?
its looks like after the IF ends, the FOR forgets the value of the varirable "abc". what to do?
please help

```js
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  if (i == 0 || i == 5) {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        var str = this.responseText;
        var text = str.split('?id = "')[1];
        var abc = text.split('";')[0];
      }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "http://example.com", true);
    xhttp.send();
  }

  fetch("http://www.example.com/post.php", {
    "credentials": "include",
    "headers": {
      "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0",
      "Accept": "*/*",
      "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
    },
    "referrer": "http://www.example.com/index.php",
    "body": "id=" + abc + "",
    "method": "POST",
    "mode": "cors"
  });
}
```

Comment: `abc` is a local variable in the anonymous function.

Comment: Why are you using both `XMLHttpRequest` and `fetch()`?

Comment: It's also run asynchronously, so even if you fix the variable scope, the variable won't be assigned when `fetch()` runs. You need to call `fetch()` from the callback function.

Comment: because I dont know how to get the content of the URL response with fetch. so i used the xmlhhtprquest for that. :(

Comment: Every tutorial on using `fetch()` shows how to get the contents of the response.

Comment: `fetch(...).then(response => response.text()).then(text => { do something with text })`

Comment: You're only setting `abc` when `i` is 0 or 5. What should go into the fetch body in other cases?

Comment: 0 ~ 4 will have the same value of ABC, and 5~9 will have the same value of ABC. the 0~4 and 5~9 values of ABC are different. when i use TEXT to get the content, how i can find the string "?id=" in the text? there is a split code for it?

Comment: `text` is the same as `this.responseText` in the XHR code.

Comment: So for each GET request you want to do 5 POST requests with the same ID?

Comment: yes I do. and its hard for me. because i dont know how to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't access `abc` outside the XHR `onreadystate` function. It's a local variable, and it's also assigned asynchronously. So you need to perform the `fetch()` calls from there.

So you should use nested loops. One loop performs the two `GET` requests, and then you do 5 POST requests in the callback function of that.

You can do everything with Fetch instead of mixing XHR and Fetch. You should use `encodeURIComponent(abc)` to ensure it's encoded properly.

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  fetch('http://example.com', {
      method: "GET"
    })
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(str => {
      let text = str.split('?id = "')[1];
      let abc = encodeURIComponent(text.split('";')[0]);
      for (let j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        fetch("http://www.example.com/post.php", {
          "credentials": "include",
          "headers": {
            "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0",
            "Accept": "*/*",
            "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
          },
          "referrer": "http://www.example.com/index.php",
          "body": "id=" + abc,
          "method": "POST",
          "mode": "cors"
        });
      }
    });
}
```